# Activity-Fragment Communication w/ Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, dagger-hilt

I have an app with a single activity but with many Fragments. I am using `ViewModel` for my Activity-Fragment communication. Lately, I am using Hilt, and I am having a problem now communicating between my activity and fragments.

My Viewmodel

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class AppViewModel @Inject internal constructor(
): ViewModel() {

    private var _data = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val data: LiveData<String>
        get() = _data
    fun insertData(dataStr: String) {
        _data.value = dataStr
    }
}
```

My MainActivity

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val mViewModel: AppViewModel by viewModels()
    private var dataString: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        mViewModel.data.observe(this, {
            dataString = it
        })
    }
}
```

One of my Fragments

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ReportFragment : Fragment() {

    private val reportViewModel: ReportViewModel by viewModels()
    private val appViewModel: AppViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View { 
        ...
        appViewModel.insertData("Hello")
        ...
    }
}
```

When I run the app, I am getting `null` as a result of `data`. Any solution to solve this?

Comment: Use `activityViewModels<AppViewModel>` to get the shared View model .Right now you have two View model instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the exact issue, but you get the `ViewModel` inside your `fragment` using `by activityViewModels<AppViewModel>` and not `by viewModels`

EDIT:

Also, I just noticed you are using an `internal` constructor. Try using only `inject constructor` once and let me know if it fixed it for you :)

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I tested w/ and w/o internal but both works. What is best practices and can you explain?

Comment: please find the complete explanation of `internal` modifier here :)  
  https://kotlinlang.org/docs/visibility-modifiers.html#constructors